# How to bind to specific property in list box

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to change the boldness of text in list item on first selection.

Xaml:

```
<DockPanel >
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding EmailsCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Sender}"  Name="SenderLabel" FontWeight="{Binding IsRead,  Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
                        <!--Style="{StaticResource Sender}"-->
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Subject}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Date}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
```

View model:

```
public Email SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            _selectedItem.IsRead = true;
            OnPropertyChanged(this,"SelectedItem");

        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public bool IsRead
    {
        get { return _isRead; }
        set
        {
            _isRead = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(this, "IsRead");
        }
    }
```

How can i bind to "IsRead" property of selected item in list?
The current way goes over all Emails in the beginning and doesn't change anything after.

Comment: Have you tried to set the UpdateSourceTrigger in the binding of SelectedItem to PropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a `DataTrigger` with out the need of a converter

```
 <DockPanel >
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding EmailsCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Sender}"  Name="SenderLabel" >
                            <Label.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Label">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>                                            
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRead}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Label.Style>                                
                        </Label> 
                        <!--Style="{StaticResource Sender}"-->
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Subject}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Date}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
```

Update: here the corresponding Model/ViewModel

```
  public class Email:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isRead;
    public bool IsRead
    {
        get { return _isRead; }
        set
        {
            _isRead = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }  
    private String _sender ;
    public String Sender
    {
        get
        {
            return _sender;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_sender == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _sender = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<Email> _emailsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Email>(){new Email(){Sender = "FirstSender",IsRead = true},new Email(){Sender = "SecondSender",IsRead = false}};

    public ObservableCollection<Email> EmailsCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _emailsCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_emailsCollection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _emailsCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private Email _selectedItem=new Email(){IsRead = true};
    public Email SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            _selectedItem.IsRead = true;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: It should ! Check My update and verify your model / ViewModel

Comment: each item you select will be Bold, since your : _selectedItem.IsRead = true; !!
If you don't wan't that behavior, don't update the IsRead  Property !!

Comment: You are welcome, please mark it as an answer if it did help you